# db.session.commit() is not working on importing CSV file in postgresql(Heroku)

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

[image: .]
db.session.add() is working but db.session.commit() is not working when i am going to import CSV file in postgresql(Heroku)

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is from CS50 Project2. Please right click on the `books.csv` and then click to `edit` the file. After that in the first line delete headings of the file. They are `isbn, author, title, year` and check that each value is seperated with `,`(comma).